# IntelliJ html comment shortcut is not working

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 2017.3.5 (Ultimate Edition).

The shortcut to comment line (Ctrl+/) (and block comments) are not working in IntelliJ for HTML files (it works fine on JavaScript and Java files but it doesn't do anything for .html file)

If I manually add in the comments, IDE recognizes it. So, only shortcut is not working. Any idea what I could try?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I have tested (Ctrl + Shift + /) or (Ctrl + /) .
Both are working fine in the html file

Comment: yes, it was working fine for me at one stage, but then it suddenly stopped working. i will just upgrade to latest version and see if it works. Cheers.

Comment: strange because for me it works but only with the `/` key on the numeric keyboard and not with the same symbol on the punctiation keys.